# outside redis connectivity issue installed on ec2 amzon linux

Tags: redis

I am not able to connect with redis from outside, (connection refused error) which is installed on EC2 running on Amazon Linux, however, i am able to connect if I do it locally on the box (via redis_cli)

I have tried out the following to rectify the problem but no luck please see if anyone has an answer to this

- changed config file and commented bind 127.0.0.1
- changed config file and added bind 0.0.0.0
- changed config file and made protection mode to off
- made sure the ports are open in security group of EC2 Instance
- built the redis on Amazon Linux to make sure the there is no binary issue

Comment: 127.0.0.0 should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: yes it is typo in question edited the same

Comment: Great. Now change it to 0.0.0.0 (IRL, not here) and you should be able to connect "from outside" :)

Comment: I have tried that as well and it's my bad, I should have added that as well in question at first place, edited the question again

Comment: looks like it was an issue of the instance itself, I made a new instance and everything worked smoothly, admin please close this question